# [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (SECCreateCredentials()).]SSL Security error Communicating with Win 10 OS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssl, tls1.2

I'm getting this error when my windows application communicating to SQL Server 2008 R2.

Application framework .Net framework 4.6.2

[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (SECCreateCredentials()).]SSL Security error.

And this error occurs when I run my application in Windows 10 OS but it's communicating in Win 8 OS.

I tried to force enable TLS 1.2 by the below code

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 but still the error exists.

Help me to resolve it.